# Break on exception in Java for "just my code"

Tags: java, debugging, visual-studio-code

In a Java project, how can I configure **VS Code** to only break on an exception in **"just my code"**?  I've messed around w/ the `Uncaught Exceptions` & `Caught Exceptions` but they are not scoped to my code.

It seems like a generic feature was implemented, [Debug Protocol: Support more flexible handling of exceptions](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-debugadapter-node/issues/64), but I'm not sure how to apply it to a Java project.

> We've added support for exception configuration to the debug protocol ([microsoft/vscode-debugadapter-node#64](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-debugadapter-node/issues/64)).  [Source](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/11552#issuecomment-264884939)

---

I see there's [an option for Node.js](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/nodejs-debugging#_skipping-uninteresting-code-node-chrome):

> VS Code Node.js debugging has a feature to avoid source code that you don't want to step through (AKA 'Just My Code'). This feature can be enabled with the `skipFiles` attribute in your launch configuration. `skipFiles` is an array of glob patterns for script paths to skip.

---

Something like [Visual Studio -> Enable or disable Just My Code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/just-my-code?view=vs-2019#BKMK_Enable_or_disable_Just_My_Code).

Comment: GitHub Issue: [Break on exception in Java for “just my code”](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-java-debug/issues/756)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In the new 0.27.0, when you want to break on exception for "Just My Code", you can add the following settings for that.
> [source](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-java-debug/issues/756#issuecomment-659264364)

```
"java.debug.settings.exceptionBreakpoint.skipClasses": [
    "$JDK", // Skip the JDK classes from the default system bootstrap classpath, such as rt.jar, jrt-fs.jar.
    "$Libraries", // Skip the classes from application libraries, such as Maven, Gradle dependencies.
    // "java.myPackage.myClass"
],
```